# Making glowing orb with light rays?

Tags: materials, light, eevee-render-engine

[image: glowing orb]

Is there a way to make something like in the picture? I prefer using EEVEE and no compositing. Basically just a glowing orb with light rays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are 2 ideas based on the same principle: create holes in an Icosphere, put a Point light inside and surround it with a Volumetric Scatter cube (density 0.04).

The first idea creates "transparent" holes using a voronoi texture node setup and uses the "Is Camera Ray?" Light path node to hide the holes to the camera. Quite versatile as it can be used on any object without modifying geometry.

[image]
[image]

---

Second idea: remove random faces in the back side of the icosphere. Allows to keep a simple material on the sphere but requires it to always face the camera to avoid seeing the holes.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Works fine, but if you look at the sphere from another view, you'll see the holes. Any fix for this?

Comment: I updated my answer